# How do I fix a large gap at the bottom of an exterior door?

Tags: doors, gap, draft

We have an exterior door with a large gap at the bottom latch-side corner.  The top of the door sits flush with the door stop, but the bottom does not. This causes a decent draft that we’re trying to eliminate.

The door is older and not a new installation. The entryway is covered, so out of the elements of mother nature.

What steps would we take to bring the door flush and eliminate the gap/draft?

[image: View from inside]

[image: Exterior. Top sits flush to door stop and gradually pulls away as you go down]

[image: Exterior. Bottom has large gap resulting in cold drafts]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a trim piece with a gasket such as this:

[Door jamb trim with gasket kit](https://www.lowes.com/pd/M-D-7-ft-x-2-in-White-Top-and-Sides-Door-Jamb-Kit-Vinyl-Foam-Door-Weatherstrip/3200767)
[image]

There are plenty of options out there, but any home improvement store should stock something like this.